# Boxplot, how to match outliers' color to fill aesthetics?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to match boxplot's outliers color to the fill color which is set by aesthetic (scale_colour_discrete).

Here is an example.

```
m <- ggplot(movies, aes(y = votes, x = factor(round(rating)),
    fill=factor(Animation)))
m + geom_boxplot() + scale_y_log10()
```

This generates plot below. How do I change those black dots to be reddish/greenish colors used in the body?  outlier.colour option of the boxplot seems to pick one colour across, and not as aesthetic, if I understand correctly.  I dont mind using colour aesthetics if that helps.

[image: Original Version]

---

**Edit:**

Adapted [this solution (Changing whisker definition in geom_boxplot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765482/changing-whisker-definition-in-geom-boxplot).  The horizontal dodging is reset by stats_summary and I couldn't figure out how to get it back.  I'd ptobably drop outliers and stretch whiskers as needed since I know how now.

```
# define the summary function
f <- function(x) {
  r <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95))
  names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  r
}
# define outlier function, beyound 5 and 95% percentiles
o <- function(x) {
  subset(x, x < quantile(x,probs=c(0.05))[1] | quantile(x,probs=c(0.95))[1] < x)
}

m <- ggplot(movies, aes(y = votes, x = factor(round(rating)),
    colour=factor(Animation)))
m <- m + stat_summary(fun.data=f, geom='boxplot')
m <- m + stat_summary(fun.y=o, geom='point', aes(colour=factor(Animation)))
m + scale_y_log10()
```

[image: Failed attempt]

Comment: This is impossible with the current release but will be possible in the next version.

Comment: @kohske, maybe you could still make an answer out of your comment. If yosukesabai accepts this answer it is clear to the SO community that this question is solved. (and it get's you some rep :)).

Comment: Actually I found kohske's answer ["Changing whisker definition in geom_boxplot"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765482/changing-whisker-definition-in-geom-boxplot) ,  which may be adapted to solve my problem.  Hope it won't be too nasty...

Comment: @kohske, could you elaborate on what would be fixed in new version and time frame for this?   I just with position='dodge' works across different geometry provided x scale is discrete.  Is this what is in progress?

Comment: @yosukesabai -- Nice question and solution.  Would you be willing to cut out your edit, and put it into an answer to your own question?  You can then accept it, and users can easily see that the question has a good answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, i dont think my "solution" is acceptable...  When I figure out how to dodge those two dataset apart, I will do what you said.  Thanks for comment tho.

Comment: @yosukesabai: `o <- function(x) {subset(x, x < quantile(x)[2] -1.5*IQR(x) | quantile(x)[4] +1.5*IQR(x) < x)}` and `m + geom_boxplot() + scale_y_log10() + stat_summary(fun.y = o, geom="point", aes(colour=factor(Animation)))` gets you a little further

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @koshke said, having the outliers colored like the lines of the box (not the fill color) is now easily possible by setting `outlier.colour = NULL`:

```
m <- ggplot(movies, aes(y = votes, x = factor(round(rating)),
    colour = factor(Animation)))
m + geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NULL) + scale_y_log10()
```

[image: boxplot with coloured outliers]

- `outlier.colour` must be written with "ou"
- `outlier.colour` must be outside `aes ()`

*I'm posting this as a late answer because I find myself looking this up again and again, and I also posted it for the related question [Coloring boxplot outlier points in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273148/coloring-boxplot-outlier-points-in-ggplot2?rq=1).*

Comment: i tried to check your answer works before i accept your answer, but somehow my R installation got screwed.  i trust you and just made it accepted answer!

Comment: @yosukesabai: there's no haste to accept late answers for old questions. Hope you got your installation working again.

Comment: Note that this doesn't match the fill color, as the title of the OP would suggest, but it does match the outline/line color - which was what I needed. +1

Comment: @RyanStochastic: you're right - I just copied from the other post. However, setting the fill color is straightforward.

Comment: It seems that this solution doesn't work anymore for ggplot2 1.0.0 and R 3.1.1. Any ideas how to get matching outlier colours for the new version?

Comment: it seems that in ggplot2 2.2.1, you only need to specify `aes(..., color = some_factor_level)` to get this effect, do not need `outlier.colour = NULL`

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution to the fact that setting `geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NULL)` doesn't work anymore in newest versions of R (@jonsnow speaks about version 1.0.0 of ggplot2).

In order to replicate the behaviour that @cbeleites propsed you simply need to use the following code:

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(colour = NULL))
m <- ggplot(movies, aes(y = votes, x = factor(round(rating)),
            colour = factor(Animation)))
m + geom_boxplot() + scale_y_log10()
```

as expected this produces plot with points that match the line color.

Of course one should remember to restore the default if he needs to draw multiple plots:

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(colour = "black"))
```

The solution was found by reading the [ggplot2 changelog](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS) on github:

> The outliers of `geom_boxplot()` use the default colour, size and shape from
>   `geom_point()`. Changing the defaults of `geom_point()` with
>   `update_geom_defaults()` will apply the same changes to the outliers of
>   `geom_boxplot()`. Changing the defaults for the outliers was previously not
>   possible. (@ThierryO, #757)

*Posted here as well: [Coloring boxplot outlier points in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273148/coloring-boxplot-outlier-points-in-ggplot2)*

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do this, editing raw grid object.

```
library(ggplot2)

match.ol.col <- function(plt,aes.cp='fill') {
  # matches outliers' color to either fill or colour aesthetics
  #   plt: ggplot layer object having boxplot
  #   aes.cp: aetsthetic from which copy color.  must be either 'fill' or 'col'
  # returns grid objects, so print it wigh grid.draw(), not print()
  if (aes.cp %in% c('color', 'colour')) aes.cp <- 'col'
  grob <- ggplotGrob(plt)
  bps <- getGrob(grob, 'boxplots', grep=T)
  for (bp in bps$children) {
    p <- getGrob(bp, 'point', grep=T)
    if (is.null(p)) next
    r <- getGrob(bp, 'rect', grep=T)
    grob <- geditGrob(grob, p$name, gp=gpar(col=r$gp[[aes.cp]]))
  }
  return(grob)
}


m <- ggplot(movies, aes(y = votes, x = factor(round(rating)),
    colour=factor(Animation)))
p <- m + geom_boxplot() + scale_y_log10()

grob <- match.ol.col(p, aes.cp='colour')
grid.draw(grob)
```

results:

[image: demobox.png]

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue. I wanted to match style with a previous plot, so wanted black borders with coloured fill, and matching outliers.

My solution was to over-print , once with colour= and the default solid circle point, and once with fill=  and an open circle point-shape

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(colour=factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(cyl)), outlier.shape=21)
```

[boxplot with coloured fill, and black borders and median line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TtUR.png)

Comment: you can also do `outlier.colour = NA` in the second `geom_boxplot` call.

Comment: With `ggplot2` 2.2.1, I found that overprinting was not necessary. `p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(cyl)), outlier.shape=21)` was sufficient to get a fill color in the outlier dots that matched the box fill.