# How do I apply a function in R to certain columns of a data frame grouped by another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been looking at the help page for `tapply` and `by` and I'm not sure if they are the right tool for this. For example, if I have a dataframe where the columns are `Name,Value1,Value2` and I want to apply a function, say `function f(x,y) { do_something }` to `Value1` and `Value2` grouped by `Name` and get as a result a dataframe with the columns `Name,f(Value1,Value2)` how should I go about that?

I can get tapply to work in a simple case like this:

`tapply(df$Name, df$value1, mean)`

but what if my function takes as input `df$value2` as well? and is not as simple as `mean`? In other words, pseudo-notation for what I'm trying to do would be:

`tapply(df$Name, c(df$value1,df$value2), function f(x,y) { x+y+bla...})`

Comment: Maybe you can make your example more concrete...? I would suggest looking into the data.table package here, otherwise I guess you'd have some combination of `by` with `mapply`

Comment: Added something to make it more concrete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also check out `plyr`. For example

```
require(plyr)
ddply(mtcars, .variables="cyl", .fun=mutate,
      meaningless_number = mean(mpg) + disp)
```

will give you back a data frame just like `mtcars`, with the added column `meaningless_number` which is the mean `mpg` by `cyl` plus the individual `disp`. Use `.fun = mutate` to add columns, `.fun = summarize` to see summaries, and other functions for other purposes.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3505701/903061) are very good for general *apply knowledge. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15274384/903061) to be a great `plyr` tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

`by` will do the job although it will not return a `data.frame`.

```
by(df, df$Name, function(X) f(X$Value1, X$Value2))
```

The package `data.table` is better set up for this sort of thing:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,f(Value1, Value2),by=Name]
```

Will return exactly what you're looking for.