# Apply a function using 2 columns grouped by a third column

Tags: r, function, loops

I am having a similar problem to the one described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860176/how-do-i-apply-a-function-in-r-to-certain-columns-of-a-data-frame-grouped-by-ano), where I want to apply a function to 2 columns grouped by each level of a third column. I have tried both solutions presented in this post, and neither worked correctly.

Here are the first 15 lines of my data frame CMdata:

```
Interval NASC Depth_mean Form
1   0   2.976   0
1   0   4.992   0
1   0   7.008   0
1   0   9.024   0
1   0   11.04   0
1   0   12.96   0
1   0   14.976  0
2   0   2.976   0
2   0   4.992   0
2   0   7.008   0
2   0   9.024   0
2   0   11.04   0
2   0   12.96   0
2   0   14.976  0
3   0   2.976   0
```

For each Interval, I want to take the sum of Form divided by the sum of NASC (Note: only the beginning of the NASC and Form columns are 0s.) To do this I first created a simple function to do the summing and dividing:

```
CMfunc <- function(arg1,arg2){
    sum(arg1)/sum(arg2)
}
```

And now I want to apply this to each Interval, 1 through 2104. I tried the solutions presented in the above post, like so:

```
dt = data.table(CMdata)
CM <- dt[,CMfunc(CMdata$form,CMdata$NASC),by=CMdata$Interval]
```

But the output is just `23.49` for every row in the new column created. I've also tried various looping functions (`tapply`, etc.) without success. I feel like this should be very easy but I continue to get errors or incorrect output.

Comment: perhaps `setDT(dt)[,newcol := sum(Form) / sum(NASC), by = Interval]` ?

Comment: That is producing correct answers in the new column, thank you!! It does apply it to every single row though, which doesn't really matter for what I need, but others may not want that.

Comment: If you just want summary table try `setDT(dt)[,sum(Form) / sum(NASC), by = Interval]`