# Change outliers from black to colour in grouped box plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, box

I have a grouped box plot in which I want to change the outlier dots from the default of black to the colour of the boxes keeping everything else the same. There is a previous thread that provides a solution for this for a standard box plot that I am able to implement.

[Coloring boxplot outlier points in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273148/coloring-boxplot-outlier-points-in-ggplot2)

However, I want to do it for a grouped box plot.

Below is some example data and code for the grouped box plot.

```
|ID |Time |Metabolite | Concentration|
|:--|:----|:----------|-------------:|
|1  |1    |A          |            40|
|1  |1    |B          |            36|
|1  |1    |C          |            28|
|1  |2    |A          |            13|
|1  |2    |B          |           150|
|1  |2    |C          |            32|
|1  |3    |A          |            45|
|1  |3    |B          |            15|
|1  |3    |C          |            15|
|2  |1    |A          |             7|
|2  |1    |A          |             9|
|2  |1    |B          |           236|
|2  |1    |C          |            33|
|2  |2    |A          |            33|
|2  |2    |B          |            48|
|2  |2    |C          |            39|
|2  |3    |A          |            15|
|2  |3    |C          |           126|
|3  |1    |A          |            13|
|3  |1    |B          |            41|
|3  |1    |C          |            37|
|3  |2    |A          |             3|
|3  |2    |B          |           218|
|3  |2    |C          |            27|
|3  |3    |A          |             7|
|3  |3    |B          |            27|
|3  |3    |C          |             3|
|4  |1    |A          |             4|
|4  |1    |B          |             7|
|4  |1    |C          |            33|
|4  |2    |A          |           133|
|4  |2    |B          |             4|
|4  |2    |C          |            10|
|4  |3    |A          |           122|
|4  |3    |B          |            27|
|4  |3    |C          |            14|
|5  |1    |A          |             7|
|5  |1    |B          |            22|
|5  |1    |C          |            43|
|5  |2    |A          |             3|
|5  |2    |B          |             6|
|5  |2    |C          |           158|
|5  |3    |A          |            48|
|5  |3    |B          |             7|
|5  |3    |C          |            24|
|6  |1    |A          |            15|
|6  |1    |B          |            30|
|6  |1    |C          |            15|
|6  |2    |A          |            27|
|6  |2    |B          |           187|
|6  |2    |C          |             9|
|6  |3    |A          |            31|
|6  |3    |B          |            40|
|6  |3    |C          |            41|
|7  |1    |A          |            37|
|7  |1    |B          |            30|
|7  |1    |C          |            28|
|7  |2    |A          |           142|
|7  |2    |B          |            40|
|7  |2    |C          |             7|
|7  |3    |A          |            45|
|7  |3    |B          |             3|
|8  |3    |C          |            45|
|8  |1    |A          |            34|
|8  |1    |B          |             8|
|8  |1    |C          |            46|
|8  |2    |A          |           167|
|8  |2    |B          |            25|
|8  |2    |C          |            34|
|8  |3    |A          |            27|
|9  |3    |B          |            28|
|9  |3    |C          |            36|
|9  |1    |A          |            44|
|9  |1    |B          |            26|
|9  |1    |C          |            20|
|9  |2    |A          |            11|
|9  |2    |B          |            18|
|9  |2    |C          |           176|
|9  |3    |A          |             1|
|9  |3    |B          |            40|
|9  |3    |C          |            10|
|10 |1    |A          |             8|
|10 |1    |B          |            49|
|10 |1    |C          |           193|
|10 |2    |A          |            13|
|10 |2    |B          |            13|
|10 |2    |C          |            28|
|10 |3    |A          |            50|
|10 |3    |B          |            47|
|10 |3    |C          |            46|
|11 |1    |A          |            21|
|11 |1    |B          |            34|
|11 |1    |C          |            28|
|11 |2    |A          |            13|
|11 |2    |B          |            32|
|11 |2    |C          |            47|
|11 |3    |A          |            15|
|11 |3    |B          |            42|
|11 |3    |C          |             9|

ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=Concentration, fill=Metabolite)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Code formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189. When you start entering code, you need to replace the `enter code text` inside the backticks with something relevant, not just type next to or after it. Better yet, with blocks of code, it's better to use "code fences", triple backticks *on its own line* `\`\`\``, then code then another `\`\`\`` *on its own line*.

Comment: You haven't shown us what your own data structure is, how you are grouping your box plots, and why the above solution doesn't work in your use case, so it's going to be difficult to help you. Basically you are asking 'why does this work on the diamonds data set with this particular layout but not my own data with my own chosen layout?', but without telling us what your own data or layout are.