# Color outliers multiple factors in boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(101)
n=10
df<- data.frame(delta=rep(rep(c(0.1,0.2,0.3),each=3),n), metric=rep(rep(c('P','R','C'),3),n),value=rnorm(9*n, 0.0, 1.0))
```

My goal is to do a boxplot by multiple factors:

```
p<- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(delta), y = value)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(metric)))
```

The output is:

[image]

So far so good, but if I do:

```
p+ geom_point(aes(color = factor(metric)))
```

I get:

[image]

I do not know what it is doing. My goal is to color the outliers as it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805643/ggplot2-add-color-to-boxplot-continuous-value-supplied-to-discrete-scale-er). Note that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499378/ggplot2-boxplot-how-do-i-match-the-outliers-color-to-fill-aesthetics) changes the inside color of the boxes to white and set the border to different colors. I want to keep the same color of the boxes while having the outliers inherit those colors. I want to know how to make the outliers get the same colors from their respective boxplots.

Comment: you can add `+facet_wrap(~factor(metric))` but i am not sure if this satisfy you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want just to change the outliers' colour ? If so, you can do it easily by drawing boxplot twice.

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(delta), y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour=factor(metric))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(metric)),  outlier.colour = NA)
                                        # outlier.shape = 21  # if you want a boarder
```

[image]

[EDITED]

```
colss <- c(P="firebrick3",R="skyblue", C="mediumseagreen")
p + scale_colour_manual(values = colss) +   # outliers colours
    scale_fill_manual(values = colss)       # boxes colours

 # the development version (2.1.0.9001)'s geom_boxplot() has an argument outlier.fill,
 # so I guess under code would return the similar output in the near future.
p2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(delta), y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(metric)),  outlier.shape = 21, outlier.colour = NA)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. But what if I want to set my own colors for each one. I tried `colss <- c(P="firebrick3",R="skyblue", C="mediumseagreen") ` and then do `p+scale_fill_manual(values = colss)` and it is not working.

Comment: @Nestorghh; 1st `geom_boxplot()` draws the outliers with `aes(colour)` and 2nd one draws boxes (and they cover over first boxes) with `aes(fill)`. So this method needs both `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_colour_manual` to change colors of boxes and outliers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(delta), y = value,fill=as.factor(metric))) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 1)+ geom_point(pch = 21,position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0))
```

[image]