# ggplot box plot confusion

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I make a boxplot in ggplot where my whiskers, box and middle are located at specified quantiles?  For instance, I want the top whisker to be at the 95 percentile of my dataset and my bottom whisker to be at the 5% of my dataset.  I saw in the documentation for geom_boxplot, the aesthetics include ymin, lower, middle, etc. but it didn't say if these should be give as actual values or as quantiles.

Comment: You can find the exact solution in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4765608/1627235

Comment: And don't forget to give @koshke an upvote.