# Equivalent of 'range' in boxplot for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers

I am trying to get the whiskers of a ggplot2's geom_boxplot to cover the outliers. The outliers would  *de facto*  not be displayed as dots as they are encompassed by the boxplot.

If I was using the standard 'boxplot', I would be using:

```
boxplot(x, range=n)
```

where *n* would be a large number so that, instead of displaying the outliers, the boxplots's whiskers *extend* to cover the outliers.

How can this be done with ggplot2?
I've tried:

```
ggplot(myDF, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_boxplot(range = 5)
```

Note: I do not want to *discard* the outliers using something like:

```
geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I know of is to compute the box values yourself like this:

```
library(plyr)
xx <- ddply(mtcars,.(cyl),
            transform,
            ymin = min(mpg),
            ymax = max(mpg),
            middle = median(mpg),
            lower = quantile(mpg,0.25),
            upper = quantile(mpg,0.75))

ggplot(data = xx,aes(x = factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = ymin,ymax = ymax,middle = middle,upper = upper,lower= lower),
                 stat = 'identity')
```

There are some warnings on the `ddply` call, but you should be able to ignore them safely.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks.
In the meantime, I think I may have found another approach the problem, haven't tested it, though: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765482/changing-whisker-definition-in-geom-boxplot)

Comment: See also the "# Using precomputed statistics" section in `?geom_boxplot`

Comment: @Ant Yes, that would probably work as well. It basically amounts to the same thing: compute the summary stats manually.

Answer (score 9):

I suppose, that this question is still relevant, because this page in the top-3 of Google search about that outliers issue. So:

Easier way to deal with outliers is (at least in the latest ggplot as by 04 Apr 2016) is to use "coef":

```
... + geom_boxplot(coef = 5)
```

From the manual (*?geom_boxplot* output copy-paste below):

> ***coef***    length of the whiskers as multiple of IQR. Defaults to 1.5
>
> **Details**
>
> The upper whisker extends from the hinge to the highest value that is
>   within 1.5 * IQR of the hinge, where IQR is the inter-quartile range,
>   or distance between the first and third quartiles. The lower whisker
>   extends from the hinge to the lowest value within 1.5 * IQR of the
>   hinge. Data beyond the end of the whiskers are outliers and plotted as
>   points (as specified by Tukey).
>
> In a notched box plot, the notches extend 1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n). This
>   gives a roughly 95 See McGill et al. (1978) for more details.