# Change whisker definition for only one level of a factor in `geom_boxplot`

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to change the whisker definition to extend to the minimum and maximum (*i.e.*, not to consider anything as an outlier), as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4765608/1085344), but only for a *single* level of the factor that is mapped to the x-axis. The code in that answer will change the whisker definition for the entire plot.

What's the proper way, if any, to go about this?

Comment: One way would be to create two data.frames or subset the data. Something like `geom_boxplot(data = full_df, ...) + stat_summary(data = single_factor_df, ...)`.

Comment: Or create the required dimensions yourself first and then use `geom_boxplot(..., stat = 'identity')`. It does seem like this approach would be confusing, if not misleading, to the audience.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns, that's what came to mind, but when I tried it, I got `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (60): x, y, fill`. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Will this is why its best to provide sample data or make your question reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending the example linked in the question, you could do something like:

```
f <- function(x) {
  r <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95))
  names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  r
}

# sample data
d <- data.frame(x = gl(2,50), y = rnorm(100))

# do it
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  stat_summary(data = subset(d, x == 1), fun.data = f, geom = "boxplot") +
  geom_boxplot(data = subset(d, x == 2))
```

In this case, factor `x == 2` gets the "regular" `geom_boxplot`, but factor `x == 1` is the "extended".

---

In your case, and being a little more abstract, you probably want to do something like this:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  stat_summary(data = subset(d, x == "special_factor"), fun.data = f, geom = "boxplot") +
  geom_boxplot(data = subset(d, x != "special_factor"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured out my problem, and now this works beautifully. However, now the factors are not ordered in the same way as in the original data. Is there a way of fixing that?

Comment: @Will not sure? Maybe create a reproducible example and post it as a new question.