# How to preserve ordering of factors in `geom_boxplot` when subsetting data?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

In my boxplot, I needed to modify the whisker definition for only one level of the factor plotted on the x-axis, and used the method given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862390/1085344), which involves splitting the data into two separate frames and plotting them separately. This has the unwanted side effect of obliterating the ordering on the levels of the factor; they are now in the default (alphabetical) ordering.

How can I preserve the level ordering in the original data frame?

**Example:**

```r
library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds)

# This function extends the whiskers to the full range of the data, rather than
# the default IQR-based range
no.outliers = function(x) {
  setNames(quantile(x, c(0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00)), 
           c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax"))
}

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=price)) +
  geom_boxplot(data=subset(diamonds, cut != 'Ideal')) +
  stat_summary(data=subset(diamonds, cut == 'Ideal'), geom="boxplot",
               fun.data=no.outliers)
```

Comment: @JasonAizkalns, done!

Comment: add `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)`

Comment: Awesome, that works! If you want the rep, feel free to turn that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: The `scale_x_discrete` doesn't appear to change the ordering of the levels in the legend, though (in my actual code I have the equivalent of `fill=cut` as another argument to `aes`). Is there a way to preserve that ordering as well?

Comment: addressed better [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002627/ggplot2-0-9-0-automatically-dropping-unused-factor-levels-from-plot-legend) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834382/ggplot2-keep-unused-levels-barplot)

Comment: then you would also need `scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)`